# Using React hooks (useEffect and useRef) - Why ref gets updated on checkbox changes?

Tags: reactjs, checkbox, use-effect, use-ref

This is a model simulated from a real project.
Clicking **undo** button should change the state of checkboxes to the state before user changes them.
When I check/uncheck a checkbox, `appRef.current` gets updated! why?
the effect hook in *App.jsx* is only called once because its dependencies array is empty.

Confusion becomes more when you click **check/uncheck all** button then try to change the checkboxes and hit **undo** button but this time it works!!!


*App.jsx*

```
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react'
import Box from './box'

const App = () => {
    const [claims, setClaims] = useState()
    const appRef = useRef()

    const crudTrue = { Create: true, Read: true, Update: true, Delete: true }
    const crudFalse = { Create: false, Read: false, Update: false, Delete: false }
    const defaultClaims = {
        resource1: { ...crudFalse },
        resource2: { ...crudFalse, Read: true },
        resource3: { ...crudFalse, Read: true },
        resource4: { ...crudFalse }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        // this effect should be called once
        // appRef should be set once
        appRef.current = { ...defaultClaims }
        setClaims({ ...defaultClaims })
    }, [])

    return (
        <Box
            claims={claims}
            // cloning to be extra sure it is not mutated
            boxRef={{ ...appRef }}
            onChange={setClaims}
            crudTrue={crudTrue}
            crudFalse={crudFalse}
        />
    )
}

export default App
```

*box.jsx*

```
import { createElement, useEffect, useRef } from 'react'
import CheckBox from './checkBox'

const Box = ({ claims, boxRef, onChange, crudTrue, crudFalse }) => {
    const checkRef = useRef()

    useEffect(() => (checkRef.current = boxRef.current), [boxRef])

    const handleChange = ({ currentTarget: checkbox }) => {
        const xclaims = { ...claims }
        const parts = checkbox.name.split('-')
        xclaims[parts[0]][parts[1]] = checkbox.checked
        onChange(xclaims)
    }

    const handleAll = () => {
        const xclaims = { ...claims }
        let isAnyClaimFalse = Object.keys(xclaims).some((res) =>
            Object.keys(xclaims[res]).some((c) => xclaims[res][c] === false)
        )
        for (let res in xclaims) xclaims[res] = isAnyClaimFalse ? { ...crudTrue } : { ...crudFalse }
        onChange(xclaims)
    }

    const handleUndo = () => onChange(checkRef.current)

    const renderChecks = () => {
        const children = []
        for (let res in claims)
            for (let key in claims[res])
                children.push(
                    <>
                        {key === 'Create' && res}
                        <CheckBox
                            key={res + '-' + key}
                            name={res + '-' + key}
                            label={key}
                            checked={claims[res][key]}
                            onChange={handleChange}
                        />
                        {key === 'Delete' && <br />}
                    </>
                )

        return createElement('div', [], ...children)
    }

    return (
        <>
            <button onClick={handleUndo}>undo</button>
            <button onClick={handleAll}>check/uncheck All</button>
            {renderChecks()}
        </>
    )
}

export default Box
```

*checkbox.jsx*

```
const CheckBox = ({ name, label, ...rest }) => (
    <>
        <input type='checkbox' id={name} name={name} {...rest} />
        {label && <label htmlFor={name}>{label}</label>}
    </>
)

export default CheckBox
```

Output is avilable [here](https://2zifnp.csb.app/) and [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/2zifnp?file=/src/App.jsx)

Comment: Instead of passing and reusing a ref (`boxRef={{ ...appRef }}`), you could just pass the contents: `boxes={appRef.current}` or `boxes={claims}`.

Comment: You cannot pass refs like a prop. You should use React.forwardRef instead.

Comment: @EdLucas as I said, this is a model of a more complex project that needs to be like this.
But I tried what you said before posting this, It doesn't work either. I passed a ref to emphasize this question why appRef gets updated?!

Comment: @Phaki I did used forwardRef => same problem. Actually I have replaced useRef with useState and the result is the same! Maybe something is wrong with checkboxes or onChange prop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did not find the problem in your code, therefore I tried to solve it with my own solution. I changed some of the code completely. Maybe if you write back parts of it to yours you find out what was the root of the problem.

Here is the codesandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/using-react-hooks-useeffect-useref-1odx68

Comment: Oh Lord! the problem was not using JSON.parse(JSON.stringify({...claims})) in handleChange method. 
Thank you for your answer and time. By the way I meant reset instead of undo (my mistake)